# restriction to $S^n$ of an orthogonal reflexion of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ , then degree$(r)=-1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am reading about degrees in homology for topology class: Definition 22 : Let $n > 0$. Since $H_n(S_n;\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}$, for all continuous maps $f \colon S_n \to S_n$ the map $H_n(f;\mathbb{Z}) $is given by multiplication by an integer
which is called the degree of $f$ and denoted by $\deg(f)$.

I understand these things.

Now, I am asked to prove this result: Result 1: Let  $r$ be a restriction to $S^n$ of a orthogonal reflexion of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ , then degree $(r)=-1.$

I am completely clueless on how result 1 should be proved.

**Corollary 1**: The anti pod $a:S^n\to S^n  $  given by $x \to -x$ has degree (-1)^{n+1}$.

I have managed to prove this using the map $(x_1,..., x_{n+1} ) \to (x_1,...,x_{i-1} , -x_i , .., x_n)$ and that $\deg(fg) = \deg(f) \deg(g)$.

**Corollary 2**: If $n\geq 1$ , then the sphere $S^n$ has a non -singular continuous tangent vector fields $\iff n$ is odd. (Hairy ball theorem)

I am again struck on this result and don't have much to show as attempt.

Can you please give some reference of  proof of (a) and (c) using homology only?

There are a lot of proofs online but they are using other results not homology.

Thanks!

Comment: If you computed the homology of spheres using Mayer Vietoris for the decomposition of the soherest using hemispheres, you have to do induction.search the site: your question is certainly a duplicate.

Comment: To get the proper font and spacing for an operator like $\operatorname{deg}$, use `\operatorname{deg}`.

Comment: @joriki Thank you very much!